# Firebase cloud function (Node.js) for email trigger not deploying

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm stuck on deploying my first Firebase cloud function. I get the following error:

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    onDataAdded

To try redeploying those functions, run:
firebase deploy --only "functions:onDataAdded"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

This is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer")
const mg = require("nodemailer-mailgun-transport")
const handlebars = require("handlebars")
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

const emailTemplateSource = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"/template.hbs"), "utf8")

const mailgunAuth = {
  auth: {
    api_key: "12345",
    domain: "domain"
  }
}

const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(mailgunAuth))

const template = handlebars.compile(emailTemplateSource)

const htmlToSend = template({message: "Hello!"});

const mailOptions = {
  from: "demo@demo.com",
  to: "demo@demo1.com",
  subject: "Completed",
  html: htmlToSend
};

exports.onDataAdded=functions.database.ref('/Reservation/{id}').onCreate( e=> 
{
    console.log("Reservation Complete");
    const data= e.val();
    const newData= {
    email: data.email.toUpperCase()
    };
    
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully sent email.")
    }
  });


    return e.ref.parent.child('newData').set(newData);
} );
```

I've tried deploying it without the function and it deploys. I couldn't figure out what exactly is causing the error.

**P.S. I replaced the API key and the domain name**

**Edit: changed the code and called smpt.transport inside the function**

Answer (score 0):

In general, it looks like you're doing too much work at the global scope of this code, especially the call to `smtpTransport.sendMail`. It's entirely unclear why you need to send email *before* the function is even invoked.

Move code into the function invocation so it runs only when the function is invoked.  Also, while testing, minimaize the amount of code you deploy overall so you can narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Hi. I mistakenly put the smtpTransport.sendMail part before the function is invoked. I fixed it, but the problem persists.

Comment: You also probably should not read files at the global scope either.

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with package.JSON file. I had to manually add the dependencies. Now it works.